# Console input prompt loop in F#

Tags: beginner, f#

I'm learning F#, starting with baby steps. Is there a way to write this code in a more succint way, while keeping the same semantics? Maybe by using a `Seq` or something like that?

```
let rec repeatingPrompt predicate (message:string) =
    Console.WriteLine(message)
    let value = Console.ReadLine()
    if predicate value then
        value
    else
        repeatingPrompt predicate message
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! I hope you receive great answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Seq.initInfinite` and `Seq.find` to do this, though I'm not sure it's actually better:

```
let repeatingPrompt predicate (message:string) =
    let prompt _ =
        Console.WriteLine(message)
        Console.ReadLine()

    Seq.initInfinite prompt |> Seq.find predicate
```

Comment: thank you. Why do you think it is not so useful to do this? Would you have done something along the lines of what I wrote?

Comment: @Grubl3r Possibly. Both versions are about the same length, but the `Seq` version is harder to understand, since you need to know what `initInfinite` and `find` do.

Answer (score 1):

I like svick's answer but wanted to show an alternate way without using `Seq` module.
It's not very different of yours (not really an improvement), but functional programming tend to favor pattern matching over `if` tests so maybe it's more "idiomatic".

*I also replaced the use of Console with the already available (without opening System) `stdin` and `stdout` but that's anecdotic*

```
let rec repeatingPrompt predicate message =
  stdout.WriteLine (message: string) // you can put the type here too

  match stdin.ReadLine () with
  | value when predicate value -> value
  | _ -> repeatingPrompt predicate message
```